# double-quotes around hyphenated table name fails

Tags: postgresql

We use SaaS software to pull our marketing data from the cloud. When I attempt to dump the result of a query to a CSV file like so

```
psql my.server -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydb -c "\copy (SELECT 
c.*,cip.*,cipi.* FROM saas.contacts c LEFT JOIN 
saas."contacts__identity-profiles" cip ON 
cip."_sdc_source_key_vid" = c.vid LEFT JOIN 
saas."contacts__identity-profiles__identities" cipi ON 
cipi."_sdc_source_key_vid" = cip."_sdc_source_key_vid" AND 
cipi."_sdc_level_0_id" = cip."_sdc_level_0_id") to 
'/tmp/contacts.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER "
```

It fails with the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: ...EFT JOIN saas.contacts__identity-profiles ...
```

I know Postgres requires I put double-quotes around hyphenated table names but this is obviously not working. I have tried

- escaping the hyphen in the table name like so `"contacts__identity\-profiles"` but to no avail
- doubling the double-quotes around the table name but to no avail.

The issue seems related to the use of double-quotes inside the COPY command. Any way I can get around that?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the double quotes themselves?

Comment: @ccjmne I have tried that as well. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double quotes doing two separate things at once:

- The outer double quotes are for `bash` to pass that command to `psql` as one argument.
- The inner double quotes are for PostgreSQL so that you can quote your hyphenated identifiers.

You need to escape the inner quotes to get them through `bash` and into `psql`:

```
psql my.server -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydb -c "... saas.\"contacts__identity-profiles\" ..."
# ----------------------------------------------------^^ ------------------------- ^^
```

and so on. Escaping them all (from `bash`) would give you:

```
psql my.server -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydb -c "\copy (SELECT c.*,cip.*,cipi.* FROM saas.contacts c LEFT JOIN saas.\"contacts__identity-profiles\" cip ON cip.\"_sdc_source_key_vid\" = c.vid LEFT JOIN saas.\"contacts__identity-profiles__identities\" cipi ON cipi.\"_sdc_source_key_vid\" = cip.\"_sdc_source_key_vid\" AND cipi.\"_sdc_level_0_id\" = cip.\"_sdc_level_0_id\") to '/tmp/contacts.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER "
```

Comment: I was incorrectly escaping the double-quotes. Your answer got me to realize this. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.

Answer (score -1):

You can try putting complete command in single quote and then using double quotes inside for other uses as follows:

```
psql my.server -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydb -c '\copy (SELECT 
c.*,cip.*,cipi.* FROM saas.contacts c LEFT JOIN 
saas."contacts__identity-profiles" cip ON 
cip."_sdc_source_key_vid" = c.vid LEFT JOIN 
saas."contacts__identity-profiles__identities" cipi ON 
cipi."_sdc_source_key_vid" = cip."_sdc_source_key_vid" AND 
cipi."_sdc_level_0_id" = cip."_sdc_level_0_id") to 
"/tmp/contacts.csv" DELIMITER "," CSV HEADER '
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No change. I am still getting `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: ...EFT JOIN saas.contacts__identity-profiles ...`