# pq_query Syntax Error because of a hyphen. How do i write this?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pg-query

This does not work

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM time-lords WHERE user='thedoctor'";
```

I get this error:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "-"

This one does work

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM time_lords WHERE user='thedoctor'";
```

So I suppose the issue is the hyphen. What is the correct way to write this? I've tried wrapping the column name in just about everything....."time-lords", [time-lords], `time-lords` and nothing seems to work.

Comment: You'll need (escaped) double-quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751724/double-quotes-around-hyphenated-table-name-fails But you really ought to be using an underscore to prevent issues like this.

Comment: It's a good practice to wrap table and column names with backticks

Comment: @ImmortalDude It's an even better practice to make sure your table and column names are simple enough you don't need to. Dashes, spaces, and other things are allowed but are *annoying*.

Comment: @tadman it's still a good practice even if your table names are simple

Comment: @ImmortalDude *backticks* are an oddity of mysql and are  not used in Postgress

Comment: @tadman fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!  That solved the syntax error.  To get the query to filter I had to do the escape double quote on the column as well:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM \"time-lords\" WHERE \"user\"='thedoctor'";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape object names with double quotes (`"`):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM \"time-lords\" WHERE user='thedoctor'";
```